# Changing Quickbooks bill date through qbxml

Tags: quickbooks

I am currently sending an InvoiceAddRq to the quickbooks webconnector. Quickbooks 2014

when the invoice comes in it has a Bill Date of the date the invoice was imported. What XML property corresponds with changing the Bill Date from imported date to date I would like.

Answer (score 1):

Invoices don't actually have a "Bill Date" field at all. They do have an Invoice Date though, which in qbXML is:

```
<TxnDate>2014-01-07</TxnDate>
```

For example, here's a full qbXML request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="2.0"?>
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    <InvoiceAddRq requestID="2">
      <InvoiceAdd>
        <CustomerRef>
          <FullName>Keith Palmer</FullName>
        </CustomerRef>
        <TxnDate>2007-12-14</TxnDate>
        <RefNumber>9668</RefNumber>
        <BillAddress>
          <Addr1>56 Cowles Road</Addr1>
          <City>Willington</City>
          <State>CT</State>
          <PostalCode>06279</PostalCode>
          <Country>United States</Country>
        </BillAddress>
        <PONumber></PONumber>
        <Memo></Memo>

        <InvoiceLineAdd>
          <ItemRef>
            <FullName>Test Item</FullName>
          </ItemRef>
          <Desc>Item 1 Description Goes Here</Desc>
          <Quantity>1</Quantity>
          <Rate>295</Rate>
        </InvoiceLineAdd>

        <InvoiceLineAdd>
          <ItemRef>
            <FullName>Test Item</FullName>
          </ItemRef>
          <Desc>Item 2 Description Goes Here</Desc>
          <Quantity>3</Quantity>
          <Rate>25</Rate>
        </InvoiceLineAdd>

      </InvoiceAdd>
    </InvoiceAddRq>
  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Here's some other qbXML examples:

- [ConsoliBYTE QuickBooks developer wiki](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/Example_qbXML_Requests)